# Difference between AWS Fixed performance instances and AWS Burstable + Unlimited mode instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ec2

I'm planning to deploy a production environment in the AWS cloud. I'm not sure about which instance type do I choose as my servers. When I did some R&D on choosing instances types, I came to know about Fixed performance instances like (m4, m5, etc) and Burstable instances like (t2, t3, etc). I doubt I can't go with Burstable instances as we are planning to go live/production. Later I came to know about Unlimited mode in Burstable instances.

So my main doubt is If I go with Burstable mode along with unlimited mode, it will work exactly like fixed performance, right? So, any time there is a spike in compute, this mode will burst to the required performance because of unlimited mode.

Is that similar to fixed performance? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is the cost. If your t2/t3 instances stay within their accrued CPU credits then they will cost much less than the fixed performance m4/m5 instances. As long as they stay within that CPU usage limit and only go into Unlimited CPU mode rarely and for very short periods of time, then they will save you money. If they end up using Unlimited CPU mode a lot then they may end up costing more than the m4/m5 instances at which point you might as well use the fixed performance versions.

Comment: So, If we go with Burstable + Unlimited mode with 100% utilization all the time, will it cost us more than fixed performance instance cost?

Comment: Yes I believe it will. Don't take my word for it though, do the math.

Answer (score 1):

AWS EC2 T3 instances offer a balance of compute, memory, and network resources, and are designed to provide a baseline level of CPU performance with the ability to burst above that baseline when needed.
That being said , if you feel your application not CPU intensive and its doesn't usually crosses baseline its good to choose t3 to save the cost. (t3 are cheaper then t2's for linux)